# Nightwatch.js - assert.containsText I'm looking for a string but got empty (null)

Tags: nightwatch.js

Here is a spinet of my code:

```
browser
.waitForElementPresent('(//*[@class="textsize-xlarge"])[1]',5000)
.assert.containsText('(//*[@class="textsize-xlarge"])[1]', 'TEST-69554083978')
```

I want to verify that an element has a string using `assert.containsText()`. 
So I'm trying to check if the class textsize-xlarge contains text

> "TEST-69554083978"

Visually I can see that it does but nightwatch returns an error message saying expected

> "TEST-69554083978" got ""

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here and point me in the right directions?

Answer (score 0):

> browser.useXpath(); // xpath will be used as the locating strategy so
>   all the selectors you pass should be xpath selectors
>
> browser.useCss(); // switches back to css selector   locator should be
>   your xpath

let locator = "[@class='textsize-xlarge']//*[contains(text(),'TEST-69554083978')]";
// Please modify above locator as I am not aware of your DOM but I can help further if you need any help in Xpath

```
return browser
        .useXpath()
        .waitForElementPresent(locator)
        .assert.elementPresent(locator);
```

you can learn about node assertions: [Node Assertions](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html)